# Calling UIImagePickerControler present in viewdidload Doesn't Work

Tags: objective-c

I want to launch camera when my view controller loads. I tried calling takePhoto method in viewdidload but nothing happens, what did I do wrong? I am getting the following error msg:
"Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"
When I inspect element UIImagePickerController, it is nil... Interestingly, I can place a button that calls this method and when I tap the button it works fine, but not when I call it in view did load...

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto {
UIImagePickerController *uiipc=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
uiipc.delegate=self;
uiipc.mediaTypes=@[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];
       uiipc.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera|UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
uiipc.allowsEditing=YES;
[self presentViewController:uiipc animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
```

Comment: viewDidLoad is called when the view property of UIViewController is first accessed, at that time the view may be not added in the window hierarchy, take care of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Call the camera from the view did appear method:

```
  //  makeCameraOff= YES;  call this in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  if (makeCameraOff==NO){
  [self performSelector:@selector(takePic) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
 }
 }

-(void)takePic{

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate =self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the camera appearance is delayed by several seconds and ruins the effect.

Comment: It has come to my attention, however, that my request for a solution is uneccesary. The user needs to choose whether to choose existing or take an image/video, so I suppose I will need to transfer to the new view controller to resolve that first.

Comment: In addition, T_77, keep in mind that your solution puts the program in an infinite loop; whenever camera dismisses camera is called again.